# Surface plot with ListPlot3D

Tags: plotting

Mathematica function `ListPlot3D` plots only half portion of a closed surface. It appears to ignore multiple values of `z` for same value of `{x,y}`. What is the significance of this limitation that leads to define `ListSurfacePlot`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not quite sure what is the question here.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `ListPlot3D` and `ListSurfacePlot3D` is in the way they interpolate the data they are given. As you have found, `ListPlot3D` ignores the 2nd point if two data points give for one domain `{x, y}` value.

Example

```
SeedRandom[42];
xyzDataTop = RandomInteger[10, {20, 3}];
xyzDataBtm = xyzDataTop; 
xyzDataBtm[[All, 3]] = -xyzDataTop[[All, 3]];
```

This plot ignore the bottom data.

```
ListPlot3D[Join[xyzDataTop, xyzDataBtm], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image: top_plot]

And this one the bottom data.

ListPlot3D[Join[xyzDataBtm, xyzDataTop], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]

[image: btm_plot]

However, because `ListPlot3D` is designed to plot vectors of data sets, you can make use of that to fix the problem.

```
ListPlot3D[{xyzDataTop, xyzDataBtm},
  PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[1., .7, 0.]},
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image: both_plot]

`ListSurfacePlot3D` gives a quite different interpolating surface.

```
ListSurfacePlot3D[Join[xyzDataTop, xyzDataBtm],
  MaxPlotPoints -> ∞,
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image: surface]